# Excel VBA AccessApplication.OpenCurrentDatabase Not Working

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Here is what I'm trying to do with Excel VBA:

1. Copy a range in Excel
2. Open an Access database
3. Delete records from the CV table
4. Paste the new records from Excel into the CV table
5. Run a make table query
6. Close the database

The code below worked - once. After it ran successfully once, it will not run again. There is no error message - the Access DB just never opens and the macro ends. Nothing ran behind the scenes, the Access DB was never touched.

I am speculating that the error might have to do with the fact that the application was opened once and maybe not closed properly and therefore can't reopen? (No idea if this is accurate/makes sense)

```
Sheets("NAHVCV").Select
Range("A:C").Select
Selection.Copy

Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

Set appAccess = Access.Application

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase AccessDBPath
appAccess.Visible = True

appAccess.CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [CV]"
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenTable "CV", acViewNormal, acEdit
appAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPasteAppend

appAccess.DoCmd.Close acTable, "CV", acSaveYes

appAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMakFutRetroVariance"

appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

appAccess.Quit acQuitSaveAll
```

Comment: Is there a ghost ACCESS.EXE process in *Task Manager*? That's a very good instinct you have there.

Comment: `Dim...As New` creates an auto-instantiated object that is automatically re-created whenever it's re-referenced. See if splitting the declaration and the assignment makes a difference.

Comment: How do I split the declaration and assignment?

Comment: `Dim appAccess As Access.Application`, then `Set appAccess = New Access.Application`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe define the access application above/outside the sub:

Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

Sub Test()
'Add the rest of your code
End Sub

I had a similar problem to yours but once I moved the access application out of the sub, my access file opened up every time

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your questions, Ashley, I distinguish

1. How to open Ms Access Database from Excel VBA (but not necessery for point 2)
2. Update data in Ms Access table CV from Excel VBA

Ad 1.:
To open an Access Database via method .OpenCurrentDatabase from Excel application VBA, select - with early binding - in Tools|References the library "Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library" (V16.0 = Office 365).

After some tries, I understood that the opened Access Application, created by
`Set apAccess = New Access.Application`
is still linked to this object 'apAccess' created at runtime and is destoyed on ending Sub/Function, hence the object required to be defined globaly at VBA Module top, outside any Sub/Function (thanks, Brendon for the hint!) to 'remain alive' after Sub/Function ending:

```
Option Explicit,
Dim apAccess as Access.Application

Sub OpenAccessApp(sAccessPathFile as String)
Set apAccess = New Access.Application 'instantiate global defined Access object
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(sAccessPathFile)
apAccess.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Do not destroy object 'apAccess' via Set apAccess = Nothing - this will close Ms Access DB!

Ad 2.:
To update records in another Ms Access database - from Excel VBA - you don't need to open the Access data base Window, as shown in Ad 1. above, but just use Access 'build-in' DAO objects; this requires linking Excel to Access database engine library (Tools|References, select library **"Microsoft Access 16.0 database engine Object Library"** - NOT "Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library", mentioned above in Ad 1.); alternatively you can also process with ADODB (which requires a reference to another library), but below, I refer to DAO-object and -method, run in an Excel Project:

```
Sub UpdateAccData(sDBPathFileName as String) 'Parameter includes external Access Path\Filename
Dim db as DAO.Database 'define DAO object, only works when referencing to database engine library!
Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0),OpenDatabase(sDBPathFileName) 'Instantiate DAO Database object
'Run MakeTable query to build table 'CV' by SQL via Execute method:
db.Execute "SELECT 'Value1' As Field1, 815 as Field2, #05/18/2022# as Field3 INTO CV;", dbFailOnError 
'Note: Field1 becomes Short Text, Field2 = Number (Long Integer), Field3 = Date/Time
```

But, I would dissuade to use MakeTable queries: in order to build a new table 'CV', MakeTable destroyes existing table 'CV', before creating a new one. If your data includes corrupted fields, table 'CV' failed to be build AFTER old 'CV' was already destroyed; as old table 'CV' was deleted, table 'CV' is missing in the entity relation! If Forms or Queries refer to table 'CV', they generates error, when opened or launched. Hence, keep table 'CV' and just remove records by DELETE and add new records via "INSERT INTO" as shown below (please update fields and Value acc. your need):

```
'Remove records in table 'CV' by SQL via Execute method:
 db.Execute "DELETE CV.* FROM CV WHERE (((CV.Field5)='Criteria'));", dbFailOnError 'omit WHERE clause, if you would empty the whole table
'AddNew/insert new records in table 'CV' with method Execute:
db.Execute "INSERT INTO CV ( Field1, Field2, Field3 ) SELECT 'Value1', 815, #05/18/2022#;", dbFailOnError
'Alternative: Update existing records in table 'CV':
db.Execute "UPDATE CV SET CV.Field1='Value1', CV.Field2=815, CV.Field3=#05/18/2022#, WHERE (((CV.Field5)='Criteria'));", dbFailOnError
End Sub
```